# Rich Text on multiple iFrames

Tags: javascript, optimization, performance, html

Having so many loops running concurrently obviously can't be good, and the code seems overly complicated. There has to be a simpler, more efficient way to

1. Turn the designMode of all iFrames on
2. Find the three "buttons" ('a' link elements) - that when clicked affect its corresponding iFrame - depending on its className
3. Put those "buttons" into a multidimensional array/object - i.e target.rtfID.x - for easy relationship - i.e "*this* bold button affects *this* iFrame
4. Whenever a "button" is clicked, find its corresponding iFrame through the object and send the iFrame's id as an argument for another function.

```
    function richText(var1, var2) {
     document.getElementById(var1).addEventListener('click', function() {
      bold(var2);
     }, false);
    }
    function bold(target) {
     if (target != 0) {
      document.getElementById(target).contentDocument.execCommand('bold', false, null); 
      document.getElementById(target).contentWindow.focus();
     } else {
      document.getElementById('richTextField').contentDocument.execCommand('bold', false, null); 
      document.getElementById('richTextField').contentWindow.focus();
     }
    }

    function iFrameOn() {
    var rtfContainer, rtContainer, richTxt, richTxtId,
    rtf = document.querySelectorAll('div > form > iframe'), //Rich Text Field
    newPost = document.getElementById('richTextField').contentDocument.body,
    target = {}, rtfIndex = 0;
    //Turn iFrames On
    while (rtfIndex < rtf.length) {
        rtfID = rtf[rtfIndex].id;
        if (rtf[rtfIndex].contentDocument.designMode != 'On') {rtf[rtfIndex].contentDocument.designMode = 'On';}
        newPost.innerHTML = "<i style=\"color:#DDDDDD;\">What's up?</i>";   
        newPost.addEventListener('blur', function() {
            if (newPost.innerHTML == '') {newPost.innerHTML = "<i style=\"color:#DDDDDD;\">What's up?</i>";}
        }, false);
        document.getElementById('richTextField').contentWindow.addEventListener('focus', function() {
            if (newPost.innerHTML == "<i style=\"color:#DDDDDD;\">What's up?</i>") {newPost.innerHTML = '';}
        }, false);
        rtContainer = rtf[rtfIndex].nextElementSibling; //Next Element Sibling should be a div
        console.log('rtContainer is: '+rtContainer);
        richTxt = rtContainer.childNodes;
        console.log('richTxt is: '+richTxt);
        for (var i = 0; i < richTxt.length; i++) {
            if (richTxt[i].nodeType != 1 || (richTxt[i].nodeType == 1 && (richTxt[i].className == 'submit_button sbmtPost' || richTxt[i].className == ""))) {continue;}
            richTxtId = richTxt[i].id;
            target.rtfID = {};
            switch (richTxt[i].className) {
                case 'richText bold':
                    if (target.rtfID.bold != richTxtId) {
                        target.rtfID.bold = richTxtId;
                        console.log(target.rtfID.bold+' is associated with: '+rtfID);
                        richText(richTxtId, rtfID);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'richText underline':
                    if (target.rtfID.underline != richTxtId) {
                        target.rtfID.underline = richTxtId;
                        console.log(target.rtfID.underline+' is associated with: '+rtfID);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'richText italic':
                    if (target.rtfID.italic != richTxtId) {
                        target.rtfID.italic = richTxtId;
                        console.log(target.rtfID.italic+' is associated with: '+rtfID);
                        document.getElementById(target.rtfID.italic).addEventListener('click', function() {
                            richText(rtfID);
                        }, false);
                    }
                    break;
                default: 
                    console.log('Error with commenting system!');
            }
        }
        /*var obj = target.rtfID;
        for (var prop in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { 
                console.log("prop: " + prop + " value: " + obj[prop]);
                switch(prop) {
                    case 'bold':
                        document.getElementById(obj[prop]).addEventListener('click', function() {
                            richText(obj, prop);
                        }, false);
                        break;
                    case 'underline':
                        document.getElementById(obj[prop]).addEventListener('click', function() {
                            Underline(obj[prop]);
                        }, false);
                        break;
                    case 'italic':
                        document.getElementById(obj[prop]).addEventListener('click', function() {
                            richText(obj, prop);
                        }, false);
                        break;
                    default: 
                        console.log('Error in for...in loop');
                }
            } else {console.log('error');}
        }*/
        rtfIndex++;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a quite bit wrong with this code, the loops are possibly the least of it.

- A ton of commented out code and `console.log` statements, please clean this up
- Inconsistent indenting, you indent with 1, 4 or 0 spaces, pick one ( I suggest 2 )
- The underline button, it does not work
- The italics button, it does not work either
- `if (rtf[rtfIndex].contentDocument.designMode != 'On') 
         {rtf[rtfIndex].contentDocument.designMode = 'On';}`
  can be replaced with
  `rtf[rtfIndex].contentDocument.designMode = 'On';`
- `"<i style=\"color:#DDDDDD;\">What's up?</i>"` should be a constant
- This: `document.querySelectorAll('div > form > iframe')` seems awfully optimistic, are you sure that you will never use iframes for anything else? I would suggest you find a more reliable means to find the richtext iframes.
- I am not sure why you would want to put the buttons in an array, once you wire them you should no longer care about them
- You can link buttons and their corresponding iFrame through a closure: http://javascript-reference.info/javascript-closures-for-dummies.htm, which seems pretty much what the commented-outcode did.

Comment: The array was just to link the button to its iFrame. I saw no other way of doing this. The commented out code and console.log statements were for debugging purposes. The richtext iFrames will **always** be within a form element, which will always be within a div. I did it this way specifically so iFrames used in the usual manner would not be affected. As for the indents, that's how I do in my editor so my apologies for that. Thanks for your help, and I hope this all explains my reasoning for doing things certain ways.